# Display members instead of class: Sandcastle

Tags: sandcastle, shfb

I create my API doc using Sandcastle HelpFileBuilder. All fine.
In the created help file, when clicking a topic from index, it usually goes to **class**.

How to change this so the link goes to **class members**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request is detailed in the topic [Removing the separate Members topic](https://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/475210).

The next release of SHFB should include this feature by default in the VS2005 and/or VS2010 presentation styles. In the meantime, you can update the presentation style source code yourself, or use the VS2013 presentation style included in [this fork of the project](https://github.com/sharwell/SHFB/releases), which includes this feature already.